# .net c#, creating CLI app commands, unrecognized needed variable

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

I have basic code of CLI application, I have created by myself:

```
using System.CommandLine;

var rootCommand = new RootCommand("Root command for file bundler CLI");
var bundleCommand = new Command("bundle", "Bundle code files to a single file");
var bundleOption = new Option<FileInfo>("--output", "file path and name");
var bundleLangOption = new Option<List<string>>("--lang", "required langueges for the bundled output");

bundleCommand.AddOption(bundleOption);
bundleCommand.AddOption(bundleLangOption);

 bundleCommand.SetHandler((output) =>
 {
     try
     {
         File.Create(output.FullName);
         Console.WriteLine("file created successfully");
     }
     catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("ERROR: file path is invalid");
     }
      Console.WriteLine("file was created");
}, bundleOption);


rootCommand.AddCommand(bundleCommand);
rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
```

Now, I'm I want to add the option "--lang" that is written here:
`var bundleLangOption = new Option<List<string>>("--lang", "required langueges for the bundled output");`

I have to add it's action to the setHandler function, I didn't know how to do it so I asked ChatGPT and it gave me:

```
bundleCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<FileInfo, List<string>>((output, languages) =>
{
    try
    {
        File.Create(output.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("File created successfully");

        if (languages.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List of selected languages:");
            foreach (var language in languages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(language);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No languages selected.");
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: File path is invalid");
    }
});
```

But, the variable `CommandHandler` is not recogized :(
No solution I got since now didn't help me.
someone?